# how to add a child node to an xml in excel vba

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I have template of an xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manageServiceProfileRequest xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
      <subscriptionsList>
        <**subscription**>
          <scode>##SCODE##</scode>
          <sname>##SNAME##</sname>
          <action>add</action>
        </subscription>
      </subscriptionsList>
</manageServiceProfileRequest>
```

my requirement is to add any number of **subscription** nodes depending on the number of subscriptions given as input . say if the number of subscriptions are 5 then i should have 5 then my xml shoul have 5 **subscription** nodes within the  subscriptionsList tag. I have written code where i manually create a subscription node and add scode,sname and action as child nodes and then append to the parent node. What i need to use the existing scubscription node in the sample template and add it any number of times.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand the question but if your document starts off with one `subscription` node and you need to add extra `subscription` nodes then you could repeatedly: deep clone the existing `subscription` node and make the new node a child of the `subscriptionsList` node:

```
' Note the True parameter to indicate we want to do a deep clone
Set newNode = existingSubscriptionNode.cloneNode(True)

' change the values of scode, sname and action here if needed

existingSubscriptionNode.parentNode.appendChild newNode
```

More details at the MSDN references for [cloneNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [appendChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms766535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi I am getting object not set error with the following code at the highlighted line                                             Private Sub CreateVSID(n As Long)
Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0
Dim NewNode, MyNewNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

xDoc.LoadXML (Sheet1.Range("b9").Value)
Set RootElement = xDoc.DocumentElement
For Each oCountry In RootElement.ChildNodes
If (oCountry.nodeName = "subscriptionsList") Then
MsgBox oCountry.nodeName
           #####NewNode = oCountry.ChildNodes.Item(1)#####
           MyNewNode = NewNode.CloneNode(True)
   Root.appendChild (MyNewNode)

Comment: Solved the issue . Thanks for the info :)